# How to merge bower dependencies

Tags: javascript, bower

I have two js subprojects. Each of them have bower dependencies in bower.js. I want to get merged bower dependencies which will suite for both subprojects, how to do that?

Comment: Create a new bower config file that contains both sets of dependencies?

Comment: That's first thing I thought of. But can it be automated with standard tool? I can write python script parsing both js files, but may be it can be done with     something currently existing?

Comment: The config files are just JSON files, right? So use JS to load them both in, parse them, and then concatenate the dependencies blocks, and export. You'll probably need to use nodeJS due to cross-origin issues.

Comment: I think I'd prefer creating grunt.js file which will form destination vendor.js file with libs I'll choose from both of subprojects

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but I made a node script that will do that for you, just add the bowerfiles in the directory and run npm start.

It's a young project, but may give anyone who reads this a head start.

https://github.com/roscorcoran/merge-bower